# Artisan, creating tables in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I am trying to create mysql tables in Laravel 5. I created a file in `/project/database/migrations` called `users.php`:

```
[...]
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->int('number');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
[...]
```

I then tried running these commands in the `project`-folder:

```
$ php artisan migrate
$ php artisan migrate:install
$ php artisan migrate --pretend
```

None of them return *any* output and no tables are created. The database to be populated exists.

Comment: Please use this command `php artisan make:migration CreateUsersTable --create` to create migration and then run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Migration files must match the pattern `*_*.php`, or else they won't be found. Since `users.php` does not match this pattern (it has no underscore), this file will not be found by the migrator.

Ideally, you should be creating your migration files using artisan:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

This will create the file with the appropriate name, which you can then edit to flesh out your migration. The name will also include the timestamp, to help the migrator determine the order of migrations.

You can also use the `--create` or `--table` switches to add a little bit more boilerplate to help get you started:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

The documentation on migrations can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations).

Answer (score 2):

in laravel 5 first we need to create migration and then run the migration

**Step 1.**

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

**Step 2.**

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you have something new to add

Answer (score 1):

First You have to create a migration file by the Following Command!

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

Now You can add your required fields in  function up

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->int('number');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In Last you Just have to run this command to migrate your table in database

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Create migration and run only created migration.

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/0000_00_00_000000_create_users_table.php
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to give a value in the table, we need to give a command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

and after then this command line

```
php artisan migrate
```

......

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can learn from your answer. The given hint about using the `make:migration` command has already been shared five years ago

Comment: already answered by other guys. do not copy the answers.