# artisan migrate command doesn't migrate, produces no output

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I am working on my first Laravel project. I'm trying to create database migrations and run them with `artisan migrate`. The migrations aren't running and the command returns no output.

Key facts:

- I used `artisan make:migration` to create the migration file with the proper filepath.
- The first time I ran the command, it created the migration table in the database. So I know that it is hitting the database and at least doing something right.
- When I have no files in the `database/migrations` folder, I get the `Nothing to migrate` command.
- Beyond these two messages, I have received no output at all from the command. No errors, nothing. Furthermore, there are no records in the migration table in the database.
- `artisan migrate --verbose` also returns no output.
- The permissions on `storage/logs` is `drwxrwxrwx.` I am the owner of the directory.
- `storage/logs/laravel.log` doesn't contain anything pertaining to the migrations.

I've included the code for my first migration below.

This question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447385/artisan-creating-tables-in-database/41639442) in that the previous user didn't use the proper naming convention. That question contains a detailed answer about the migration process. It's not helpful because I'm not getting any output. I also reviewed the questions suggested by SO as I entered this question.

Perhaps I have something configured incorrectly? What do I need to do to get these migrations running?

**2017_01_17_151638_user.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

// Create the classes associated with user management.

class UserMigration extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('tblUser', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('name');
          $table->string('email')->unique();
          $table->string('password');
          $table->rememberToken();
          $table->timestamps();
      });

      Schema::create('tblUserPasswordReset', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->string('email')->index();
          $table->string('token')->index();
          $table->timestamp('create_date')->nullable();
      });
    }

    public function down()
    {
      Schema::dropIfExists('tblUserPasswordReset');
      Schema::dropIfExists('tblUser');
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `/storage/logs` folder is writable; it may be hitting an error and trying to log it there, and depending on your dev environment, it may not be communicating that properly.  Beyond that, perhaps include a screenshot of your terminal running the command.

Comment: In my case it was XDebug listening and stopping the script. After disabling the listener, the command went through with no errors.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

then try

```
php artisan migrate
```

Laravel keeps track of the migrations ran, so if you have run it before, it knows and wont do it again unless you roll it back and I ran into this until i rolled them back and then ran migrate again

Comment: No effect. `php artisan migrate:rollback` reports `Nothing to rollback`. `php artisan migrate` afterward does nothing. The migration table is still empty.

Comment: make:migration create_thetable.php   <-----  does this command put out anything at all?

Also does this: php artisan migrate:reset    produce anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try:`composer dump-autoload`

Then run `php artisan migrate` again

Possible issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974248/7377984

Comment: No effect. `composer dump-autoload` reports `Generating autoload files`, but still no action on `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Try `php artisan clear-compiled` followed by `composer dump-autoload` then `php artisan optimize` and finally `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 2):

For me the only way to make it work was by restarting the mysql service (in OSX, never saw this on debian).

Comment: Restarting mysql service also solves this issue on debian.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I just figured out the problem.

I created a new user in MySQL and assigned all rights to all databases through the mysql shell:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Don't forget to change the connection info in .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=user1
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the following:

- Migration files are actually being created in `database/migrations`
- Double check the log file and directory is writable
- Make sure the permissions on the `database/migrations` folders are the default that come with the laravel install
- Doublecheck the laravel.log file

Comment: The migration files are in `database/migrations`. The permissions on the `storage/logs` directory are `drwxrwxrwx.` The `laravel.log` file has some older entries but nothing pertaining to migrations.

Answer (score 0):

- First check your Services Apache and Mysql running by going to your
  localhost/phpmyadmin.
- check your terminal or cmd that you are in correct filepath
  directory.
- then write **php artisan migrate**
- if something shows let me know here if not goto your laravel.log for
  details

Answer (score 0):

Do not miss to add your migrations to DatabaseSeeder.php. Refer to this documentation [Calling Additional Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding).

Within the DatabaseSeeder add this:

```
$this->call(UserMigration::class);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem with none of the listed solutions changing anything. The unmentioned solution that works in this case for me was

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

I had wiped out everything and was starting from scratch, forgot to re init composer and install everything.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to reproduce a case where Migrations run without error yet do not migrate is by having not specified a database schema name in the config along with a connection name.

In either in the **.env** file ensure that the following settings has a value:

```
DB_CONNECTION=master
DB_DATABASE=my_databse_name
```

or alternatively in **/config/database.php** :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'master'),

'connections' => [

        'master' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_databse_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => 'cms_',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue earlier this month what i did was i checked the confiuration to mysql server carefully the restart the mysql server and the IDE itself

Answer (score 0):

I think the class name of the migration should be User and not UserMigration as laravel looks for the class using file name and your file have a slug user not user migration.